# Finishing basement wall over old exisiting window

Tags: walls, basement, windows, basement-refinishing, finishing

I'm planning to finish walling in a room in my existing basement, (It will not be a bedroom or livable area so no need for windows etc...) The original basement was built in 1940's. There is one exterior wall where there is a window.

[image: Exterior Window]

I don't really want to just wall over it for obvious reasons, but the problem I have is the outside of the window is now covered by a ground level deck and I believe the well has been capped somehow but not filled in. Basically I have no access to the exterior side of the window. It doesn't leak or anything when it rains or gets snow built up on the deck etc... but, How should I go about either taking the window out and filling the frame back in? or should I just seal it up somehow and wall over it?

For reference: I do plan to put polystyrene foam board insulation / vapor control... etc before the studs and stuff.

Comment: Welcome. Your question is rather broad. You're either asking how to fill a hole in a foundation or how to seal over the window. You'll need to decide that for yourself and ask a more specific question. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: I would keep the window and frame around it.  It does not leak now is no proof it will not leak in the future or plans change.  Can make a small cupboard with doors for holding knickknacks or something, but leave the window easy to get at.

Comment: For completeness, an alternative solution is removing the window and installing steel dowels around the opening. You would then install forms and place concrete to fill the opening. A bladeless reciprocating saw is a decent poor-man's concrete  vibrator to minimize voids, and hydraulic cement is good for filling any voids you discover after stripping the formwork.

Comment: @popham are you suggesting to fill in the window well with concrete?

Comment: @Huesmann, just the wall. You can use 2 chunks of plywood on each side. Lay opposite wall sides on top of each other and drill holes through both to get matching layout. Then use threaded rods to pinch the wall from both sides with the plywood chunks. No need for exterior access, then, to place the outer forms.

Comment: @popham so you just leave the exterior form in place?  I assume the intent is to fasten the threaded rods to the outside form before installing it in place?

Comment: Would removing the window and filling with concrete still provide protection from any water intrusion? My concern would be that the new concrete wouldn't interface well with the old concrete and there would end up being gaps or places for water to seep through.

Comment: @Huesmann, yeah, nut and washer on the outside before sneaking the pieces in. For the final pair (the upper one in my imagination), the threaded rods would need to be too long by about 5" so that each bolt could get loosely installed while maintaining access before tightening. Maybe the access hole for placing the concrete would provide adequate access, though. I hadn't thought too hard about that part of the design.

Comment: Kfly, you'll find many advocates for hydraulic cement for sealing it from water. I'm skeptical of sealing it with anything from the inside. I would use hydraulic cement to smooth the surface and apply a tiler's waterproof membrane if I had lots of moisture and an exterior moisture barrier everywhere else. Alternatively, I guess you could use pressure treated plywood for the exterior form and paint it with asphalt or some other hydrophobic coating.

Comment: Is there a window well?

Comment: @Huesmann There is a well, however it has been capped off I believe and a ground level deck has been built over the top of it so I have no way to access it from the exterior. Today I plan to see if I can get some of the deck boards up and gain access, but I don't think I can.

Comment: What do you mean by "capped off?"  Is there any chance water would drain there?

Comment: @Huesmann, I'm not sure. The deck that is covering over the well, I can not see between the boards on. If I shine a light from inside of the window up towards the deck I do not see deck boards, so I am unsure what is on top of the well between it and the boards.

Comment: @Kfly does the window not open?